# Java optional isPresent check in ternary expression

Tags: java, sonarqube, option-type

I'm wondering why Sonarqube is giving me a

`Call "user.isPresent()" before accessing the value.`

warning for this statement:

```
String name = user.isPresent() ? "<default>" : user.get().getName();
```

Is this a bug in the Sonarqube validator, or do i miss something there?

Comment: In any case, it's better to use `String name = user.ifPresent(...).orElse(...);`

Comment: @DodgyCodeException you mean `user.orElse(new User("<Default>")).getName()`. Or something like this to provide a "default user". (`ifPresent` return a boolean (or void with a `Consumer`)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException can't chain after `ifPresent()`, but `orElse()` should still be used.

Comment: Apologies, I meant `String name = user.map(User::getName).orElse("<Default>");`

Comment: @DodgyCodeException nice, I always forget the `Optional.map` ! Seems cleaner than the solution to create a "default user" like above or another solution.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you may have your ternary wrong.  Can you try this:

```
String name = !user.isPresent() ? "<default>" : user.get().getName();
```

Comment: But I am with Dodgy here: the ral solution is to use what he suggested in his comment. Optional has `orElse` so that you exactly do not need to write such code that makes use of a ternary operator like this.

Answer (score 2):

```
String name = user.isPresent() ? "<default>" : user.get().getName();
```

Is wrong because you should return default, when optional is **not present**.

On the other hand, `isPresent` shouldn't be used for such purposes. Optional has methods that are tent to handle such use cases. You could use for example:

```
String name = user.map(User::getName).orElse(defaultName);
```

Where map is a method which substitutes the user's name if user `isPresent`.

The `isPresent` should be used for filtering or asserting rather than for replacing the following block of code:

```
if (val == null) {
    //do sth
} else {
    //do sth else
}
```

I strongly recommend [this](http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) article in which the Optional is nicely introduced.